# CodeIgniter 'where' not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

This is a search function I made, it gets the search term and displays fine. `HM_Jobs` has 3 options for **JobStatus:** `Open`, `Accepted` or `Complete`.

However the search is also pulling results from the `Accepted` and `Complete` rows when I run it, why isn't the WHERE statement stopping this from happening?

```
function search_jobs($search) //This function checks a search term against the job title and description.
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('HM_Jobs');
    $this->db->like('JobTitle',$search);
    $this->db->or_like('JobDescription',$search);
    $this->db->where('JobStatus','Open');  

    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result(); 
}
```

Comment: Try echo $this->db->last_query() to see your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 $this->db->select('*');
 $this->db->from('HM_Jobs');
 $this->db->where("(JobTitle LIKE '$search' OR JobDescription LIKE '$search')"  );
 $this->db->where('JobStatus','Open'); 
 $query = $this->db->get();
```

You can see your query executed by using  `echo $this->db->last_query()`

Your query creates like

```
where JobTitle like 'search' or JobDescription  like 'search' and JobStatus='Open'
```

But the query you need require something like

```
  where (JobTitle like 'search' or JobDescription  like 'search') and JobStatus='Open'
```

Comment: Got this error:

Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'asf' in 'where clause'

SELECT * FROM (`HM_Jobs`) WHERE (JobTitle LIKE asf OR JobDescription LIKE asf) AND `JobStatus` = 'Open'
Line Number: 62

Comment: Sorry,I miss single qoutes

Comment: Last point: Use $this->db->escape_like_str() to escape the inputs. More info in http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following query

```
function search_jobs($search)
{
    $query = $this->db->select('*')
                  ->from('HM_Jobs')
                  ->where('JobStatus','Open')
                  ->where("(`JobTitle` LIKE '%$search%' OR 
                            `JobDescription` LIKE '%$search%')",null,false)
                  ->get();
    return $query->result(); 
}
```

Comment: Gave me the following error:

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%asf%') AND `JobStatus` = 'Open'' at line 3

SELECT * FROM (`HM_Jobs`) WHERE (`JobTitle` LIKE '%asf% OR `JobDescription` LIKE '%asf%') AND `JobStatus` = 'Open'

Comment: @user3574766 I've edited my answer. please check now

Comment: @user3574766 it should work this is the way to use where clause with grouped condition,i am curious i guess you are not using his answer properly